# HTML IDs that start with a number

Tags: javascript, html

I generate GUIDs for id's in my HTML like

```
<div id="9121c01e-888c-4250-922f-cf20bcc7d63f">...</div>
```

According to HTML5 specs, this is valid. However, if you try to find such a element with document.querySelector or document.querySelectorAll, you'll get an error saying that the selector is invalid.

I know that for CSS rules, such an ID is not valid. Does the querySelector methods of 'document' rely on CSS?

Comment: Somehow my sample line disapeared: <div id="A9121c01e-888c-4250-922f-cf20bcc7d63f"></div>

Comment: This happens since it's not a valid CSS selector. You can either add a prefix, use getElementById or change you selector to be `[id="9121c01e-888c-4250-922f-cf20bcc7d63f"]`

Comment: I know this isn't the answer, but wouldn't it be better to write them into data-guid="" rather than putting them in the ID class?

Comment: If you are searching with an `id`, why not just use `.getElementById`? It's faster and simpler.

Answer (score 4):

> Does the querySelector methods of 'document' rely on CSS?

The strings you pass `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are CSS selectors. So yes, they follow the rules of CSS selectors, one of which (as you mentioned) is that an ID selector cannot start with an unescaped digit. So they don't rely on CSS per se, but they follow the syntax of CSS selectors.

You can select that element either by *escaping* the first digit (which is fairly ugly*):

```
var e = document.querySelector("#\\39 121c01e-888c-4250-922f-cf20bcc7d63f");
```

...or by using an attribute selector:

```
var e = document.querySelector("[id='121c01e-888c-4250-922f-cf20bcc7d63f']");
```

Example:

```js
document.querySelector("#\\39 121c01e-888c-4250-922f-cf20bcc7d63f").innerHTML = "Yes!";
document.querySelector("[id='9121c01e-888c-4250-922f-cf20bcc7d63f']").style.color = "green";
```

```html
<div id="9121c01e-888c-4250-922f-cf20bcc7d63f">...</div>
```

Of course, if you're *just* getting the element by its ID and not using a compound selector starting with an ID, just use `getElementById`, which doesn't use a CSS selector, just the ID value as plain text:

```
var e = document.getElementById("9121c01e-888c-4250-922f-cf20bcc7d63f");
```

You only need the other form if you're using a compound selector (`"#\\39 121c01e-888c-4250-922f-cf20bcc7d63f > span a"`), or passing a selector string into something you don't have control over that you know will use `querySelector`.

---

* In a CSS selector, `\` followed by up to six hex characters (plus a space if you don't use all six) specifies a character code in hex. `0x39` is the character code for the digit `9`. And of course, we had to escape the `\` in the string literal since otherwise it would have been consumed by the string literal.

Comment: document.getElementById(); Works with first character being number, would seem a better choice?

Comment: @Riku: I did mean to mention that, yeah, **if** you're not combining it with something else (e.g., `[id="...."] > span a`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they use CSS selectors

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

```
Syntax
element = document.querySelector(selectors);
where

element is an Element object.
selectors is a string containing one or more CSS selectors separated by commas.
```

But as you append the GUID as ids you can use `document.getElementById();`

It supports this case.